# getx how to pass parameters from one controller to another?

Tags: flutter, get

Lets say I have the following two views: **products_screen** & **product_screen**,
and the corresponding two controllers: **products_controller** & **product_controller**

**products_controller** query a DB for a list of products, **products_screen** shows this list of products.
The user can select a product from this list, which takes him to the **product_screen** where he should be able to see this product details.

I see no need to query the DB again, but rather use the data in **products_controller** and pass it to **product_controller**, so that it can be used in **product_screen**.

What is the right way to do that?

One option I can see here is to pass the productModel to the **product_screen** (when navigating), and then call the **product_controller** with that data, but it doesn't feel right...
any other suggestions?

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question and add both controllers to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using **Getx**, you can set **arguments property** when you want to move from a screen to the next screen like this :

```
Get.to(YourScreen(), argument: YourDataWhateverItCanbe),
```

then in the YourScreen() you can call `Get.arguments` whenever you need to use it or store in a variable like this :

```
dynamic theDataFromPreviousPage = Get.arguments;
```

then use it

Hope this help

Comment: Looks like this method works in the controller as well, so that solves the issue. Thanks :)